# How to get the sum of a column of a relationship with groupBy in Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have to models. A Sales model and a Product model with commission belonging to the sold products. They look like this:

Sales

```
+----+-------+---------+
| id | agent | product |
+----+-------+---------+
| 1  | Peter | A       |
+----+-------+---------+
| 2  | Aron  | B       |
+----+-------+---------+
| 3  | Peter | B       |
+----+-------+---------+
```

Products

```
+----+---------+------------+
| id | product | commission |
+----+---------+------------+
| 1  | A       | 10         |
+----+---------+------------+
| 2  | B       | 15         |
+----+---------+------------+
```

How do I get the total commission grouped by agent and sorted by the total commission. So in this case the result would be:

```
+----+---------+------------+
| id | agent   | commission |
+----+---------+------------+
| 1  | Peter   | 25         |
+----+---------+------------+
| 2  | Aron    | 15         |
+----+---------+------------+
```

I have created a relationship between the models like so:

```
public function product(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(Product::class, 'product', 'product');
}
```

Comment: what is your expected output in the result?

Comment: Defining `product` as a foreign key in a relationship cause a conflict in the data when retrieving the data because you have two `sales` with the same `product` but different in `agent`. Instead, stick to the default foreign key i.e. `id`.

Comment: @JSTECH yes this would be ideal.. but in my case not possible because i retrieve the data from another application where i only have the name of the product

Comment: @MiteshRathod its the third table in the question

Comment: @TheStompiest As far as I understand it's very simple and no need to dive deeper `Product::orderBy('commission')->get();`

Comment: What do you mean by 'total commission by agent'? Does `Peter` get the commission of 25 (10 for `A` and 15 for `B`)? Why your sample output is grouped by product, not by agent?

Comment: @Jared you are correct. I've updated the table. The result should be the agent and then total earned commission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Eloquent can provide the join-then-aggregate in one query at the model level. You could fetch everything and group manually with PHP, but you can do it with query builder like that:

```php
$aggregrated = \App\Models\Sale::query()
    ->join('products', 'sales.product', '=', 'products.product')
    ->groupBy('agent')
    ->select('agent', \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::raw('SUM(commission) as commission'))
    ->get();
```

But in my opinion such things should be moved to the DB-level views:

```sql
CREATE VIEW sales_aggregated AS 
    SELECT sales.agent as agent, SUM(products.commission) as commission
    FROM products
        INNER JOIN sales
        ON sales.product = products.product
    GROUP BY agent
```

With this view you could create an Eloquent model and use for read-only operations in the very same way as a regular model (including relations).

P.S. as long you are using the `id` surrogate key for your products, I believe you should rely on that key for relations. I mean replacing `sales.product` by `sales.product_id`.